# Select a specific value in a group using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset with below data.

```
id status div
1  True    0
2  False   2
2  True    1
3  False   4
3  False   5
1  False   5
4  True    3
4  True    10
5  False   3
5  False   3
5  True    2
```

I want my output as

```
id status  div
1  True    0
2  True    1
3  False   4
4  True    3
5  True    2
```

If true is present in the group i want it to be true else if only False is present i want to be False.

I have tried using Pandas group by but unable to select the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by helper `Series` with first `True`row per groups if exist:

```
s = (df.sort_values(['status','id'], ascending=False)
       .drop_duplicates('id')
       .set_index('id')['div'])
print (s)
id
5    2
4    3
2    1
1    0
3    4
Name: div, dtype: int64

df1 = df.groupby('id')['status'].any().reset_index()
df1['div'] = df1['id'].map(s)
print (df1)
   id  status  div
0   1    True    0
1   2    True    1
2   3   False    4
3   4    True    3
4   5    True    2
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get total row after groupby

Comment: @shashank - total of `True`s rows? Then for group `4` it is not `3 + 10 = 13` ?

Comment: if it is true it can pick any true row. it should not add. we can take first true value